# Chart Chart with percentage values ​in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

So far I have correctly the values ​​that I want in my graph but I want to add the "%" and since they are decimal type I don't know how to do

```
obj = '<% = CanalAforoPercentage%>';
    data = JSON.parse (obj);
    ctx = document.getElementById ("chartCanalPercentage"). getContext ('2d');
    userStrengthsChart = new Chart (ctx,
```

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it by applying this example:
http://www.java2s.com/example/javascript/chart.js/chartjs-and-data-labels-to-show-percentage-value-in-pie-piece.html